# Trouble with Example for Convergence in Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

I am a bit confused by an example used to illustrate the concept of "convergence in distribution"

[image]

Intuitively, this makes sense, since if we choose a large number of points from the distribution of $X$, the distributions for $X$ and $X_n$ will appear the same. However, the formal definition for convergence in distribution says:

[image]

and in the given example, it doesn't seem that the sequence of cdfs converge pointwise for any non-zero value of $x$. At $X=1$ for example, the cdfs of the odd $n$ converge (trivially) to $F(-1)$ while the cdfs for even $n$ converge to $F(1)$.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems: Your "trivial" convergence statement is not true and you forgot to take into account the fact that the distribution is assumed to be symmetric: This means that

$$
F(x) + F(-x) = 1 \forall x 
$$

So let's see what happens for odd $n$ and $x \in \mathbb R$ (e.g. $x=1$ in your example):

$$
F_{X_n}(x) = \Pr [-Y \leq x] = \Pr [Y \geq -x] = 1 - \Pr [Y < -x] = 1 - F_Y(-x)= F_Y(x) 
$$

In the above I also used the fact that $Y$ is a continuously distributed random variable.